# Pnotify Notifications wrong colour

Tags: c#, css, jquery-ui, pnotify, bootstrap-notify

Hello i am trying to change the colour of each notification but i cant find from where. I am using jqueryui as styling. Bellow you can see how the error and success notification appears in my screen!

[image]

[image]

This is is the code that i am using in order to build dynamically the script of calling pnotify

```
string script1 = @"var displayIcon = " + displayIcon + @";
                            $(function(){
                                new PNotify({
                                    title: '" + messageString + @"',
                                    styling: 'jqueryui',
                                    width: '400px',
                                    opacity: 0.9,
                                    type: '" + typeLowercase + @"',
                                    icon: displayIcon,
                                    hide: false,
                                    buttons: {
                                        sticker: false
                                    },
                                    animation: {
                                        effect_in: 'fade',
                                        effect_out: 'slide'
                                    }
                                });
                            });";
```

Comment: What do you mean by colour? The text colour or the background colour? From what I know of pnotify, you specify a type of either `info`, `notice` or `error`. If you want a custom style, you can use the `addclass` option.

Comment: Hello there as you can see i am using styling: 'jqueryui', but i cant find where in the css file what i need to change in order to change the bg colour of the notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `background-colour` option when you initialize PNotify. You'll need to use the `addclass` option for any custom styles. `ui.pnotify .ui-pnotify-container` defines the background color of the notification. Appending an additional class to the end of `ui.pnotify` (e.g. `ui.pnotify.myclass`) and assigning it a `background-color` will allow you to make use of `myclass` in the initialization stage.

So, if you'd like to assign the notification a background colour of red, you'd create a css rule like this:

```
.ui-pnotify.red .ui-pnotify-container {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Then, in the initialization stage, you can use the `addclass` option like this:

```
$(function() {
  new PNotify({
    title: '" + messageString + @"',
    styling: 'jqueryui',
    width: '400px',
    opacity: 0.9,
    type: '" + typeLowercase + @"',
    icon: displayIcon,
    hide: false,
    addclass: 'red',
    buttons: {
      sticker: false
    },
    animation: {
      effect_in: 'fade',
      effect_out: 'slide'
    }
  });
});
```

When you specify the custom class name in the `addclass` option, you don't need to include `ui-pnotify`; just the name of the class that follows (in this case `red`).

In the fiddle below, I've created two custom classes (`red` and `blue`). Change the value of `addclass` to `red` or `blue` to see the custom background colour:

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/9ue2dubc/)**